# React Dev tools won't initialize

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-devtools

I am new to react and am following a tutorial where they ask to install react developer tools. However on installing the react developer tools doesnot light up. It does not activate. I followed the trouble shooting options and allowed access to file URls . yet it still doesnt work.

[image]

[image]

What do I need to do to make it work?

Please help

Comment: Have you tried opening a page/app instead of a chrome settings url? Somewhere you know React is running, like https://reactjs.org/? Installing the extension should be just about all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you are trying to access certain page to check if it's React-written. There are visual indicators when you are looking at React-written page and your DevTools will turn to blue icon, otherwise, something else being used to produce this. For the testing purposes try visiting Facebook page and pay attention to the icon.